# How do I boot up Ubuntu on Windows 8 from a Linux USB key?

Tags: boot, usb

I did all of the steps on creating a special Linux USB key with Ubuntu on it, but how do I boot up Ubuntu? I was told that I plug in the USB into my computer before I start it up, it will go directly to Ubuntu, and when I unplug it after shutdown and start it up again it would go back to Windows 8. It does nothing just goes to Windows 8. I'm completely new to Windows 8 (literally got it today) so is it possible to use it like I said? If so how? Thanks

Comment: Did you research this site? The *Related* column has lots of similar posts - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - >

Comment: With UEFI or BIOS you do have to tell system which device you want to boot from. You may have a one time boot key like f12 (check manual) or go into UEFI and choose what to boot. http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do what you want.

You can either change the bios settings to always boot from the USB ( if it is available ), if it is not, then it will boot from the hard-drive.

To do this, go to the bios ( most probably by pressing the del key repeatedly after turning on your computer ), and then under the Boot menu, find an option which says boot device priority, and there, give the USB a higher priority than your hard-drive.

Or, you can just go to the boot device options before booting and select your usb.

For this, after starting your computer, repeatedly press the key which takes you to the boot device options ( usually F8 or F12, it should be indicated on the first screen you see when you turn on your computer ), and there, select your USB.